# In Facebook Graph API, how do I post on someone's wall as the identity of another person?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have 2 users in my database. I have both access_tokens for these two users.

I want **A to post on B's wall**.   However, I am using the app_access_token, not the user's access_token (because the user access_token expires).  Therefore, when the post is created, **B is posting on B's own wall**.

```
var uri = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + fb_id + '/feed?access_token='+ app_access_token
```

I want A to post on B's wall, but still use the app_access_token.

Answer (score 0):

The access token is what essentially identifies the user performing the action.  When you use the app access token it is in fact the application performing the action.  You will have to use the correct (user) access token in order for a post to appear on behalf of a user and not your application.

If you still want to use the app access token then you might consider including the users names in the message of the post.  That way even though it is originating from your app - the actual post details the correct :

> [user name] has sent you this message

Comment: But then I will run into offline "expiration" problems...The only way I don't run into these problems is using the app's access token.

Comment: have you been following the [offline_access permission's deprecation?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/)... There is still a way to extent the validity of the token for an extra day... But in the end Facebook is opting out of this functionality.

Comment: How do I "Mention" somebody in the message? (tag somebody)

Comment: This is a touchy subject - it is possible but it is considered a hack and Facebook is aware of it.  It wont be possible for much longer.. not sure if it even is still possible - here is the syntax : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/4776656/558021

Comment: well... IMO the offline_access feature (which would have been perfect for your scenario) was an unnecessary and dangerous feature.  I for one am glad that it is being deprecated. (no offence to you of course :)  Maybe if you detail the behavior of your application for this feature people will be able to suggest alternative methods for achieving the same effect...

Comment: so, every time I want my user to post on another user's wall, I have to take him through the oauth dialog again ?

Comment: If your requirement is that the post is made without user interaction then you'll have to use the app access token and the solution in my answer.  However - if you use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) (that means that the post is user initiated), then you will not have to worry about any permissions or access tokens.  You just call the dialog and Facebook will handle the rest :)